# Navigate to full URL (including query parameters) from string retrieved from local storage in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my Angular 5 app, I use an external auth provider for user authentication. I have links configured that are meant to open specific sections in the app via query string parameters. In order to save the original desired URL through the authentication process, I save it to local storage.

When I retrieve the URL, I can't seem to construct the call to router.navigate() to properly handle routing AND include the original query parameters. Is this possible?

An example URL might be `https://myapp.com/contacts/new?assign=customer&id=123`

I have tried working with 

`this.router.navigate([fullRedirect], { queryParamsHandling: 'merge' });`

But I end up with a URL like `/contacts/new%3Fassign%3Dcustomer%26id%3D123` in my browser and Angular Router is treating `new%3Fassign%3Dcustomer%26id%3D123` as the `:id` of `/contacts` rather than routing to `/contacts/new` and including the original URL parameters.

My goal is to have a generic solution that can work with various URL parameters as the app grows.

Have you had success with this kind of thing? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: So the question boils down to: how to navigate to an URL that contains URL parameters

Answer (score 2):

This issue was a tricky one to explain (sorry!). I was losing query parameters when the app was first loading after coming back from an external authentication step (via Auth0).

The full URL was saved to the browser's local storage, but I couldn't achieve the desired combination of navigating to the correct Angular Route and keep the original query params.

Hard-coding the handling of the query params in my auth service proved to be inflexible and cumbersome.

I ended up getting this working with a combination of `NavigationEvent` settings and the use of `navigateByUrl()`.

```
private redirect() {
  let fullRedirect = decodeURI(localStorage.getItem('postAuthRedirect'));
  if (!fullRedirect) {
    fullRedirect = '/';
  }
  // Preserve any query parameters and fragments from the original URL
  const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParamsHandling: 'preserve',
    preserveFragment: true
  };
  // Do the redirect
  this.router.navigateByUrl(fullRedirect, navigationExtras);
}
```

The scenario is pretty specific... picture loading a complex URL from a bookmark or a separate system that "deep links" to the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are on to but the reason you are getting that modified url is because whenever you store in your local storage or cookie, it gets encoded.

So after retrieving it from the local storage you can use this

variable = decodeURI(retrievedFromLocalStorage)

and then use this variable in your route

Comment: Thank you for this tip. I made sure that I had `decodeURI()` in there when reading from local storage, and I also used `encodeURI()` when saving it to local storage in the first place.